# Combining an OR statement in a while loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop

I am building a small function to allow a player to select their shape at the beginning of a Tic Tac Toe game (pick X or O)  and for some reason I am having trouble with the following code.   The while statement does not work with OR statement in it.   The code runs when I remove either shape != "o" or  the shape != "x", but with both options in the while loop, I  never escape the while loop and am constantly asked what shape do I want to be.

```
def selectShape():
    shape = ""
    while shape != "o" or shape != "x":
        shape = raw_input("What shape do you want to be? x or o? ")
    if shape == "x":
        print "The computer is player o"
    else:
        print "The computer is player x"
```

Comment: `shape != "o" or shape != "x"` is a tautology; there is no string that is both `"o"` and "x"`. You meant "and" there. (Or, more idiomatically, `while shape not in ["o", "x"]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are constantly asked because one will always be true.

If you pick X then: shape != "o"
If you pick O then: shape != "x"

You should probably use AND instead of OR.

while shape != "o" AND shape != "x": 
 That way if neither are correct it will continue to prompt. It will break and continue if one is X or O.